# Use __str__ of each instance attribute for a class's __str__

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way in Python 3 to recursively call private member variables unique `__str__` functions programmatically? Something like:

```
class A:
  def __str__(self):
    return "A"

class B:
  def __str__(self):
    return "B"

class C:
  def __init__(self):
    self._A = A()
    self._B = B()

  def __str__(self):
    for var in vars(self):
      return str(var)
```

When calling the individual private members, it works fine. Would like a method to do it dynamically however.

Thanks so much.

Comment: `__str__` should return a string.  You don't do the print in `__str__`

Comment: Ah yes, typo. Thanks for that.

Comment: The standard way is to use [PEP 557 dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html). Prior to that, the [attrs project](https://attrs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) was most popular, and is still most flexible.

Comment: I'm happy to listen to how to do this with a dataclass. Anyone have an example?

Comment: @BradSolomon Right, but once you have the metadata, you can define your own functions however you want if you really need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`vars`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) function returns a dictionary where the keys are the variable names (as strings) and the values are the values of the variable. So iterating over the values should work.

```
class A:
  def __str__(self):
    return "A"

class B:
  def __str__(self):
    return "B"

class C:
  def __init__(self):
    self._A = A()
    self._B = B()

  def __str__(self):
    output = ""
    for _,var in vars(self).items(): #Iterate over the values
      output += str(var) #Use the str() function here to make the object return its string form
    return output #Need to return instead of print since that is what the __str__() function should do
```

You can add some kind of separator (like a `\n`) between the values if you want. Just replace `str(var)` with `str(var) + "\n"`.

Comment: This works, which is excellent and thank you so much. If anyone else has opinions on this approach, I'm all ears. Thanks again! What exactly is the _,var doing here though? Grabbing the semi-privates?

Comment: @BradSolomon Just checked it. The keys are the variable names, written as strings. So in this case, they are `"_A"` and `"_B"`.

Comment: @BradSolomon the keys are the string corresponding to the *attribute name*, nothing to do with the `__str__` or `__repr__` of the objects in the namespace

Comment: @BradSolomon the representation will be used if you print the dict, however

Comment: @troy_s The `_,var` is what is used to iterate through a dictionary. The underscore would be the key, while `var` is the value. I use an underscore whenever I'm not actually using that particular variable, like in this case.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yeah I see what you're saying.  My previous comment admittedly was nonsensical.  curious for my own understanding if you see anything wrong with the answer below

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the dictionary keys; `vars()` is `self.__dict__`:

```
>>> class A:
...     def __str__(self):
...         return self.__class__.__name__
... 
>>> class B:
...     def __str__(self):
...         return self.__class__.__name__
... 
>>> str(A())
'A'
>>> repr(A())  # "long-form" the hex-string is id()
'<__main__.A object at 0x10f65a908>'

>>> class C:
...     def __init__(self):
...        self.A = A()
...        self.B = B()
...     def __str__(self):
...         return '\n'.join(self.__dict__)
... 
>>> C()
<__main__.C object at 0x10f65aa58>
>>> print(C())  # Uses str(C())
A
B
```

[`vars(self)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) is effectively `self`.  In turn, [`self.__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__) is a `dict` used to store an object’s (writable) attributes.

```
>>> C().__dict__
{'A': <__main__.A object at 0x10f65aa90>, 'B': <__main__.B object at 0x10f65aac8>}
```

The signature is `'\n'.join(iterable)`, and when you iterate over a dictionary, you iterate over its keys, which suffices in this case.

#### Note on Dataclasses

I'm not totally sure if (Python 3.7+) dataclasses are an easier solution here.  That's because they automatically implement a `__repr__()` but not a `__str__()` as far as I can tell:

```
>>> from dataclasses import dataclass
>>>
>>> @dataclass
... class C:
...     _A: object = A()
...     _B: object = B()
... 
>>> c = C()  # still uses repr() for each field
>>> str(c)
'C(_A=<__main__.A object at 0x10f373828>, _B=<__main__.B object at 0x10f373940>)'
```

In other words, you'd need to replace `A.__str__` with `A.__repr__` (same for `B`, which is maybe not something you want to do in the first place with regards to those two classes.)

Comment: Yeah this just happens to work because your attribute name just happens to be the same as what `str` would return by the objects being referenced by those attributes

Comment: From what I can tell, this doesn't work. The reason it is working in this example is because the names of the members (`A` and `B`) are the same as their string representation. If you change the names to `_A` and `_B`, like in the original question, this outputs `"_A"` and `"_B"`, which are not the correct string representations.

Comment: That's because of `self.__class__.__name__` though, no?  @kungfushark.  If you want to manually alter that, just would need to use a `str` literal in place

Comment: @BradSolomon What I mean is that, if classes `A` and `B` had actual `__str__()` functions, this solution would not work. If, say, `str(A("x"))` was supposed to be `"x"` (would be defined in `A().__str__()`), this solution would not work, and would instead just output whatever the member name in `C()` was.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you shouldn't be using `__repr__`?

Anyway, here's an example using `attrs`, beacuse I'm stuck on Python 3.5. With `dataclasses` it will work in a similar manner.

```
import attr


class A:
    def __str__(self):
        return 'A'

class B:
    def __str__(self):
        return 'B'

@attr.s
class C:
    a = attr.ib(default=attr.Factory(A))
    b = attr.ib(default=attr.Factory(B))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = C()
    print(c) # __str__ defaults to __repr__

    def __str__(self):
        bits = ['<C']
        for a in self.__attrs_attrs__:
            bits.append(' %s=%s' % (a.name, getattr(self, a.name)))
        bits.append('>')
        return ''.join(bits)
    C.__str__ = __str__
    print(c) # custom __str__
```

Comment: This is for prettied output, so string seems the most logical choice here. Not certain however.